# How to change the structure of JSON

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, json

I have a JSON like this

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
```

how can I convert its structure like this

```
[{
"option_id": "a",
"option_value": "1"
},
{
"option_id": "b",
"option_value": "2"
},
{
"option_id": "c",
"option_value": "3"
}]
```

I tried `JSON.stringify`, `result.push([i,data[i]])` etc but to no success so far

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396006/convert-json-to-associative-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `map` function, which accepts a callback function.

Also, you should use `Object.keys()` method in order to get the `keys` of an object.

```js
var object={"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
console.log(Object.keys(object).map(function(item){
    return {"option_id": item,"option_value":object[item]};
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `Array#reduce`.

```js
var json = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},
    result = Object.keys(json).reduce(function(s,a){
      s.push({ "option_id": a, "option_value": json[a] });
      return s;
    }, []);
    
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: reduce vs map. map wins.

Comment: @Kinduser, Sometimes MAP winns and sometimes REDUCE winns. I create a liitle `game` to test the performance. Please have a look here : https://jsfiddle.net/b2c47cj1/1/ . Maybe you can improve the algorithm,

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Yeah, map wins. It's like 10-7 for map with every try.

Comment: @Kinduser, by the way: +1 for your answer.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Your is better, +1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ECMAScript 5.1 or newer (or a suitable polyfill) then the following will do what you have asked for

```
let value = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3};
let newValue = Object.keys(value).map(key => ({option_id:key,option_value:a[value]}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//with old syntax   
q = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
arr = []
for(i in q) {
  arr.push({'object_id': i, 'object_value': q[i] });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var object = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}, resultArr = [];

for(var key in object) {
resultArr.push({
"option_id": key,
"option_value": object[key]
});
}

console.log(resultArr);

var outputArr = Object.keys(object).map(function(eachItem){
return {
"option_id": eachItem,
"option_value": object[eachItem]
};
});

console.log(outputArr);
```